# jQuery load() callback causes POST instead of GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the jQuery's load() method so that I can load a page fragment into a new page. As far as I can tell, this is only possible with `load()` and `get()` does not support page fragments.

After the load is completed, I need to be able to call a function to style the results of the load. However, this causes the load function to send a `POST` instead of a `GET` as per the documentation that states 
`.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )` "The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.". The URL I am hitting only accepts `GET` so this causes a 404 for the `load()`.

How do I achieve loading a page fragment and using a callback after it is complete without changing to `POST`?

```
 $('#search').load('?id='+parent_id+' #search', style_searches())
```

Comment: Is style_searchs supposed to be the callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your only issue is that instead of passing callback function into `load` you are passing result of its invocation.

Correct code:

```
$('#search').load('?id='+parent_id+' #search', style_searches);
```

Note, that the second parameter is `style_searches` not `style_searches()`.

Comment: This answer is really good. But now I've come across another problem where I need the callback to be a function sent with an argument. Would you be able to update to include an example of that too?